# C++ Type const* p and Type const* const p

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, mutators

I have this `Type const* p` method. Is it sure that p's pointee, `*p` will never be modified ?

Same thing with `Type const* const q`.

Comment: Related, not same question. i am wondering whether i can modify pointee of p if p is a `Type const* p`. Tks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Type const* p` is a pointer to const object with type `Type`. To be read left to right, with pointer pointing to type defined by everything before the star. The same way, `Type const* const q` is a const pointer to a const object with type `Type`.

Also, `*p` cannot be modified through p. `p` is defined so as to const-point to `*p` and promise not to modify it. However, `*p`, p's pointee, can be modified by any other pointer pointing at it.

For example, we can have

```
Type t;
Type const* pc = &t;
Type *pnc = &t;
```

`pc` promises not to alter t, `pnc` does not. Let's say class Type bears a const `inspect() const` method and a non-const `mutate()` method. Then we could have

```
pc->inspect();
pnc->inspect();
pnc->mutate();
```

whereas this one would rise compiler's error:

```
pc->mutate();
```

`Type const* const q` is a pointing to a const object and `*q` cannot be modified through q, just like with p. What is more, pointer `q` cannot be modified: it cannot be assigned a pointee a second time.

***Also, although this may sounds very strange, you are allowed to change in code the object of type `Type` pointed by pointer `Type const* p` -- but not through `p`.***

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can't be modified but, it will only guarantee that the variable the pointer points to will be constant and it is not the same thing as `Type const* const q` which also guarantees that pointer is constant